# Get the SUM of a value partitioned by a column as a measure

Tags: sum, powerbi, dax, measure, partition-by

I have data like this:

| date | serial | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-17 | A | 1 |
| 2021-08-17 | B | 0 |
| 2021-08-18 | A | 0 |
| 2021-08-18 | B | 1 |
| 2021-08-19 | A | 1 |
| 2021-08-19 | B | 1 |

what I want is:

| date | serial | val | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-17 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-08-17 | B | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-08-18 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-08-18 | B | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-08-19 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-08-19 | B | 1 | 2 |

I found some examples to do it with a calculated column

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Sum-over-partition-by-order-by-in-DAX/td-p/215856
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Sum-over-partition-by/m-p/442516

, however as I know a calculated column does not work with slicers, so I need to code it with a measure.

As an example if I move the time slicer to 2021-08-18 the outcome should be:

| date | serial | val | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-18 | A | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-08-18 | B | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-08-19 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-08-19 | B | 1 | 2 |

Is this somehow possible with a dynamic measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this with the following measure

```
Dynamic Running Total = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table 1'[val]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Table 1'[date]),
        ISONORAFTER('Table 1'[date], MAX('Table 1'[date]), DESC)
    )
)
```

[image: solution]

Comment: It works, can you explain why it already contains the partitioning on serial?

Comment: In DAX, aggregation happens for whatever is visible in the filter context. In this code, I asked DAX to perform running total and I don't have to explicitly mention the partitioning elements. Whatever levels I bring on the viz, i.e. columns from table, i.e. more filter context, DAX will unfold the results based on all those levels.